# XML operation in ColdFusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I have problem with my XML, in some case I receive XML with extra data. I want to delete it, because it crashes my result.

```
 <a:ExceptionInformation>
    <a:ExceptionInformation>
        <a:Description>XXX</a:Description> 
        <a:ExceptionType>YYY</a:ExceptionType>
    </a:ExceptionInformation>
</a:ExceptionInformation>
 <a:ExceptionInformation>
    <a:ExceptionInformation>
        <a:Description>AAA</a:Description> 
        <a:ExceptionType>YYY</a:ExceptionType>
    </a:ExceptionInformation>
</a:ExceptionInformation>
```

I want to find node where ExceptionType == YYY and delete all:

```
 <a:ExceptionInformation>
    <a:ExceptionInformation>
        <a:Description>AAA</a:Description> 
        <a:ExceptionType>YYY</a:ExceptionType>
    </a:ExceptionInformation>
 </a:ExceptionInformation>
```

Comment: Pleas provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: Why do you need to delete these nodes? Can't you simply ignore them?

Comment: The output should have two `ExceptionInformation` nodes not one.

Comment: Without more context, the phrase "crashes my result" is very ambiguous. You need to provide more specific details ie 1) your code 2) any error messages 3) brief description of how the result differs from what you expected.